# Including JMS with mac os x Lion and eclipse / sts

Tags: eclipse, maven, jms, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I have the latest version of STS and the latest version of the JDK from the Apple Developers web site.

When trying to use the Spring Jms Template I am getting:

```
The type javax.jms.Destination cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
```

So within my IDE javax.jms does not resolve.  I do not know where I am supposed to get this interface, or if it is supposed to be included already?  Either way I installed javaee-api-6.0.jar into my maven repositor which includes the interface.  So now if I type at the top of a class 'import javax.jms.Destination' the autocomplete now works... but I am still receiving exactly the same error.  I am completely confused by this.

Comment: How are you running this when you see that error?  However it's being run doesn't have the javaee-api-6.0.jar in it's classpath..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
</dependencies>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
        <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>repository.jboss.org-public</id>
      <name>JBoss repository</name>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

The above seemed to solve my problem, another version of the required jar was included in the given repository